# Trying to Insert QBO Credit Memo with IPP.NET

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am using IPP.Net to attempt to insert a single CreditMemo into Quickbooks Online.  I have been successful inserting an invoice with similar code.  My code for inserting the CreditMemo is as follows:

```
Try
                        Dim qboCreditMemo As New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CreditMemo
                        Dim qboCreditMemoHdr As New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CreditMemoHeader
                        Dim qboCreditMemoLine As Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CreditMemoLine
                        Dim CreditMemoLines As New List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.CreditMemoLine)
                        Dim CreditMemoItemAttributes As Qbo.ItemChoiceType2()
                        Dim CreditMemoItemValues As Object()

                        For Each row In tblTrans.Rows
                            If bFirstRow Then
                                'Set CreditMemo header
                                qboCreditMemoHdr.DocNumber = "SMA" & CStr(row("batch_id"))
                                qboCreditMemoHdr.TxnDate = Format(row("acct_date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
                                qboCreditMemoHdr.Msg = row("batch_descr")
                                qboCreditMemoHdr.CustomerId = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType
                                qboCreditMemoHdr.CustomerId.Value = row("iface_owner_id")
                                qboCreditMemo.Header = qboCreditMemoHdr

                                bFirstRow = False 'only do this once
                            End If

                            'Lines
                            qboCreditMemoLine = New Qbo.CreditMemoLine
                            qboCreditMemoLine.Desc = row("descr")
                            qboCreditMemoLine.Amount = row("amount_owner")
                            qboCreditMemoLine.AmountSpecified = True
                            CreditMemoItemAttributes = {Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.ItemId, Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.UnitPrice, Qbo.ItemsChoiceType2.Qty}
                            CreditMemoItemValues = {New Qbo.IdType With {.idDomain = Qbo.idDomainEnum.QBO, .Value = row("iface_item_id")}, row("unitPrice"), row("quantity")}
                            qboCreditMemoLine.ItemsElementName = CreditMemoItemAttributes
                            qboCreditMemoLine.Items = CreditMemoItemValues
                            qboCreditMemoLine.ClassId = New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.IdType
                            qboCreditMemoLine.ClassId.Value = row("iface_class_id")
                            CreditMemoLines.Add(qboCreditMemoLine) 'Add line to list of lines
                        Next row

                        qboCreditMemo.Line = CreditMemoLines.ToArray  'Add CreditMemo lines to CreditMemo lines property
                        resultCreditMemo = commonService.Add(qboCreditMemo)           'Add CreditMemo to request
                        Return "OK"

                        'Catch exID As Intuit.Ipp.Exception.IdsException
                        'Return exID.Message
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Return ex.Message

                    End Try
```

I got an error with message 'Internal Server Error'.  It seems to be an IdsException.  As indicated in my other article, I was able to get detailed information for a BatchRequest through the Fault and Error objects.  However, I do not understand how to get the details on this error for a single invoice using Dataservices.

I think I may need better error handling, assuming there is more information available for this error.  And, I need help figuring out why the same properties that I set for an invoice would not work for a CreditMemo.  Unfortunately the documentation in the Intuit website where the required properties are listed does not include a CreditMemo (though it includes an Invoice).

Answer (score 4):

CreditMemo is not supported in QBO:

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/0500_Supported_Entities_and_Operations

Comment: Are you sure CreditMemo is not supported in QBO?  Though I did notice that CreditMemo is absent from the list in your link.  It is shown in the IPP.Net Devkit 2.0 class library at http://developer.intuit.com/IntuitDataServicesSDK/?topic=html/714c1b2e-3473-fadd-0753-358ebb114480.htm.  And, it is also shown in the Object Browser within Visual Studio.

Comment: The DevKits are generated from the service schemas and may contain entities that are not supported.  Please use the API documentation as your source of reference for supported entities and operations.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same issue, and the problem was that the qty and amount should not be negative. I changed it on my creditmemoLine and it worked